# Fixed button at bottom of UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, interface-builder

I have a view controller which has a tableview subview.  I have made the tableview height smaller, leaving about 46 pixels for a button that needs to stay at the bottom and not scrolled with the table.

I have played around changing the height of the table view (in IB) and it doesn't seem to change anything.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the UIButton at the same level as the UITableView - both are subviews of the main view. Do you have the UITableView as the view of the view controller?

Comment: Yes, I do have the tableview as the view of the controller. I guess I'm not sure what you mean both at the same level?  I've tried it a bunch of different ways...one I just dropped a table view into the controller.  And then tried to drop a view at the bottom of that.  I also tried a view controller, and then dropped the table view into the view and then shortened the tableview and put a button at the bottom... that didn't work right either.

Comment: What it needs to look like is the view controller having a view which you don't use as anything except for the parent of the table view and the button. When the tableview is the controller's view it occupies the full size of the controller. Another way of putting it is that the controller's view is the table view, but you want the controller's view to be something else - which can hold other views in the arrangement you want, like the button and the tableview.

Comment: Do I have to do this programatically instead of in IB?  When I just drop a table view and a button in the view, I get an exception saying that it loaded my nib but didn't get a UITableView.

Comment: Finally figured it out....thanks very much for leading me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done programmatically in the UITableViewDelegate:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Build a custom view
    // ...
    // Build a custom button
    // ...
    [customFooterView addSubview:button];

    return [customFooterView autorelease];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 53.0; // return your button's height
}
```

Comment: This will not place the button fixed if you have more than one section.